# PHP can run a bash file from the php shell but not when a button is clicked on webbrowser(ubuntu-firefox))

Tags: php, bash, unix

I hava a bash file that can be executed when I run it from the terminal using php -a (interactive shell), by typing:

```
shell_exec('sh /home/oceanview/run_test.sh');
```

I have created a button and when this button is clicked the bash file should be run

```
<form action="Control.php" method="post">
<input value="Continous Acquisition " name="Continous" type="submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['Continous'])) {

shell_exec('sh /home/oceanview/run_test.sh');
 }

 ?>
```

But nothing happens when I press the button. I have tried chmod +x and chmod 0777 already and there is no error showing in log.

I have to add that the interactive shell asks for my password when I run the shell_exec command  in the terminal.

Comment: i think it's because you have a space after the directory

Comment: try adding 2>&1 to your command

Comment: are you sure you have permission to use shell_exec() because most of servers don't allow this by default

Comment: @elibyy thanks it was a typo here.

Comment: @MaryE still not working?

Comment: @Mohammad yes I have a local server and it worked before with other bash files.

Comment: no still not working

Comment: print the post data .. are you sure you receive a post data ... i thing you must give your form a name

Comment: Can you elaborate?,,how can I print the post data?

Comment: I have to add that the interactive shell asks for my password when I run it in terminal

Comment: @MaryE in php section write   var_dump($_POST['Continous']);

Comment: Is all of the code which you posted in one file which is called Control.php ?

Comment: @Mawg Yes the file is called Control.php

Comment: You should separate the form and its action into two separate files. Generally, the handler should output no HTML, just validate input, perhaps do some calculation and then load an appropriate success.php / error.php file.

Comment: I didn't think you could have async IO when you post, also your not doing anything with the output of shell script. eg "$varname=shell_exec('sh /home/oceanview/run_test.sh');" and if input is required you will need to use STDIN to provide input $varname=shell_exec('sh /home/oceanview/run_test.sh << "passwodthing"');

Comment: Let's start over here. How do you expect this to behave since the `run_test.sh` script requires you to type your password? Do you want it to prompt you to enter a password from a webpage? Do you want to provide your password directly in the command?

Answer (score 0):

Under a web post request, you aren't going to be able to run a script that's interactively requesting your password (at least not without a lot of additional infrastructure, like an `expect` script).  How do you expect to be typing in your response, anyway?

Most likely what is happening is that the process is exiting on detecting that it isn't attached to an interactive terminal.  You wouldn't be able to see any output it's producing anyway, since you aren't capturing or using the result from `shell_exec()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something similar to this in order to input your password and then pass it off to the shell command

```
<form action="Control.php" method="post">
<label>Password: <input type="password" name="pwd"></label>
<input value="Continous Acquisition " name="Continous" type="submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['Continous'])) {
  $command = sprintf(
    'echo %s | sh /home/oceanview/run_test.sh',
    escapeshellarg($_POST['pwd'])
  );
  echo shell_exec($command);
}

?>
```

You can test this out from a command line by using

```
echo 'mypasswordhere' | sh /home/oceanview/run_test.sh
```